# Modify a macro to copy and paste using range and retaining formula

Tags: excel, vba

I found the code below on this site which works perfectly once I referenced the appropriate cells etc. However, I tried to modify it to keep formulas but I am not having much luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub test()
    Dim names As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nm As Variant
    Dim res As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
            On Error Resume Next
            'collect unique names
            names.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next cell

        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'change "A1:C1" to headers address of your table
        Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:C1")

        For Each nm In names
            With rngHeader
                'Apply filter to "Name" column
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=nm
                On Error Resume Next
                'get all visible rows 
                Set res = .Offset(2).Resize(lastrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0

                'if there is visible rows, create new WB
                If Not res Is Nothing Then
                    'create new workbook
                    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
                    'add sheet with name form column "Names" ("Paul", "Nick" or etc)
                    wb.Worksheets.Add.name = nm
                    'delete other sheets from new wb
                    For Each ws1 In wb.Worksheets
                        If ws1.name <> nm Then ws1.Delete
                    Next

                    'copy/paste data
                    With wb.Worksheets(nm)
                        'copy headers
                        .Range("A1").Resize(, rngHeader.Columns.Count).Value = rngHeader.Value
                        'copy data
                        .Range("A2").Resize(res.Rows.Count, res.Columns.Count).Value = res.Value
                    End With

                    'save wb
                    wb.Close saveChanges:=True, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Spreadsheet_" & nm & ".xlsx"
                    Set wb = Nothing
                End If
            End With
        Next
        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set names = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please. What row gives you the problem? Don't just post a wall of code and expect us to play detective.

Comment: I just need to know where in the code do I modify to ensure that when it pastes the data it copied from the original file, it retains the formulas and not paste it as values. I'm guessing it's here but my takes didn't work......  'copy/paste data
                    With wb.Worksheets(nm)
                        'copy headers
                        .Range("A1").Resize(, rngHeader.Columns.Count).Value = rngHeader.Value
                        'copy data
                        .Range("A2").Resize(res.Rows.Count, res.Columns.Count).Value = res.Value

Comment: The code comment is misleading. There is no pasting happening. You will need code that explicitly copies the range, then explicitly pastes the range using Paste special XLValues. Google it.

Comment: @teylyn I think he would need [`.SpecialPaste`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) with `xlPasteFormulas` instead of `xlPasteValues` to keep the formulas as he asked for.

Comment: yes, my typo. the same principle, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a part in your code which states that it copies / pastes data:

```
            'copy/paste data
            With wb.Worksheets(nm)
                'copy headers
                .Range("A1").Resize(, rngHeader.Columns.Count).Formula = rngHeader.Formula
                'copy data
                .Range("A2").Resize(res.Rows.Count, res.Columns.Count).Formula = res.Formula
            End With
```

If you copy the `.Formula` instead of the `.Value` then it should work. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a way I can retain the format from the original file? I found a code but it did not retain the format...                 
rngHeader.Copy .Range("A1") and res.copy .Range("A2") - it will copy everything including format – Dmitry Pavliv Feb 20 '14 at 14:41 2 rngHeader.Copy Destination:=.Range("A1") and res.Copy Destination:=.Range("A2") – Dmitry Pavliv Feb 20 '14 at 15:09

Comment: If you copy first "everything" (as you stated in your comment with the referenced / working code) and then use the above to paste the formulas (only) on top then you'll have the requested solution, no?

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked!!!! however, I have another dilemna, the formula is referencing the wrong row. It's referencing whatever row my parsed data was on the original file. For instance, let's say I had 10 rows on the original file (masterfile) which will then be parsed to 10 different files, the data on row 7 of the masterfile will be on row 2 of the new file. The formula on the new file is referencing row 7, therefore making the result incorrect. I hope I made sense. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not sure what you mean. But maybe this can be solved by referencial formulas? In that case you should use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula` as posted in the above solution. Give that a try and see if that helps.

Comment: you are the BEST! thank you soooooo much. That's exactly what I needed. @Ralph, thanks!